# How to get different times in the same query session using getdate()?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want a different datetime per GETDATE() statement but it shows the same value.

```
DECLARE @TimeStampEnd datetime2

SET @TimeStampEnd =  GETDATE()
SELECT 'Time  ' + CAST (@TimeStampEnd as varchar)

SET @TimeStampEnd =  GETDATE()
SELECT 'Time  ' + CAST (@TimeStampEnd as varchar)
```

Comment: `SYSDATETIME()` is more precise, but SQL can still do a lot in a very small amount of time :)

Comment: Dave, changing GETDATE() to SYSDATETIME() still returned the same values.

Comment: In addition to `WAITFOR` you could use `DATEADD(s,3,GETDATE())` or `SYSDATETIME()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system clock only has a resolution of a apprx. 3 milliseconds.  If the commands inbetween your two GetDate() calls take less time than that, then they may return the same time.

If you want to insure that they are different, then you need to take longer, by using more or slower commands, or just add a WaitFor command.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind injecting some delay there, you can use [waitfor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx):

```
waitfor delay '00:00:00.003';
```